# Can't reindex sunspot. "Solr Response: Bad Request"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat, solr, sunspot

I'm trying to use sunspot in production with tomcat-solr, in ubuntu
10.10

I followed these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
sudo apt-get install solr-tomcat
sudo service tomcat6 start
```

Then I updated my `sunspot.yml` to point the production / staging
environment to the port :8080.

But when I try to run `rake sunspot:solr:reindex` , it gives me this
message. "Solr Response: Bad Request"

It's been four days and I still can't figure ou what is
wrong =/ I couldn't find the tomcat/solr logs to get more info on
what's bad in my request.

Can someone help me?

Comment: bad request is usually you are passing somthing invalid to Solr. you can turn the solr logs to finest and check logs. also check for the query fired on solr, might get some hints for invalid fields or data

Answer (score 4):

In your case, I am willing to bet that you haven't updated your configuration files with Sunspot's default `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml`. Log files will likely be in `/var/log/tomcat6` and may complain about an *unknown field "type".*

I am not exactly sure where Ubuntu's solr-tomcat package creates the Solr home, but `/usr/share/solr` is a good place to check. You should copy Sunspot configuration files from `solr/conf` into Solr's own configuration directory and restart Solr to update the config files.

See also my answer to [sunspot solr undefined field type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104673/sunspot-solr-undefined-field-type/7118284#7118284).

Comment: BTW, to save anyone who finds this some time.  The solr/conf directory referred to above is in the sunspot_solr gem, under a directory called 'solr'.  Which actually makes it solr/solr/conf.

At the time of this writing, you can find it here: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/tree/master/sunspot_solr/solr/solr/conf