# Solr unable to reindex due to undefined field type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I've inhereted a rails app that uses Solr, which is new to me.  All I want to do for now is to get the site running locally.  I've installed solar, but when I try to get it running on the app, I have problems. I can run

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

without getting any errors, but when I try to reindex everything, like this:

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

I get the following error:

```
Execute sunspot:reindex
rake aborted!
Solr Response: undefined field type
```

I gather from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104673/sunspot-solr-undefined-field-type) that it's because of the schema.xml file. And that I have to copy that file.

I've got a schema.xml in my app's root directory and I've got another in the example directory in /usr/local/Cellar/solr/3.6.1/libexec/.  When I did the rake

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

command, schema.xml was copied into my app's solr directory.  Is there more copying that needs happen? I'm not really sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `schema.xml` in `conf` directory, under your Solr root.

Comment: Just to clarify... I need the `schema.xml` file in the `conf` directory of the `solr` directory at the root of my rails app.  Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure how sunspot uses Solr, but it has to be in Solr's root/conf. In [this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/example/solr/conf/) conf dir.

Comment: Copied my schema.xml into the correct spot, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

For Solr 4.7, copy schema.xml and solrconfig.xml from your_app/solr/conf to /opt/solr/solr/collection1 (or whatever your solr path is) and if still not working, make sure that your config/sunspot.yml is something like:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/collection1
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5
```

It is recommended to create another core (my_core) from the solr web interface, copy schema.xml and solrconfig.xml to that folder and point path to /solr/my_core

Step by step guide here: http://blog.eemglobal.com/2014/07/setup-rails-4-with-sunspot-gem-and-solr-4-7-in-production-environment-on-ubuntu-14/